# GUI to cut individual lines from a text file to create a new one

Tags: text-editor, gui

I need a Windows program that will display a text file and let me select individual lines of that file to move to a new file.  So, for example, I can select lines 4-9, 14, 22-24, 46, etc. as I scroll through the existing file, and they will be removed from that file and become lines 1-11, etc. of a new text file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/).

First mark lines clicking on the left field

[image]

Then right click on one of these dots->Cut bookmarked lines
[image]

Next create new file, mark first line (as above) and Paste
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[CudaText](https://cudatext.github.io/) editor (free) allow this using bookmarks.

[image: CudaText]

- Don't select lines, but instead place bookmarks on them - click the left-most gutter column to place a bookmark.
- Menu item "Search / Bookmarks / Copy bookmarked lines"
- Add a new file-tab, and call "Paste" from context menu
- Remove original lines, if you need it, using "Search / Bookmarks / Delete bookmarked lines"